# Strange operations behaviour with LESS

Tags: less

This one compiles:

```
.myclass {
    .mymixin(2);
}

.mymixin(@parameter) {
    width: ((@parameter*1)*12px);
}
```

This one does not:

```
.myclass {
    .mymixin(2);
}

.mymixin(@parameter) {
    width: ((@parameter-1)*12px);
}
```

Does anyone have a clue what's the problem with the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Less treats `@parameter-1` as a variable as you can tell from the compiler error:

> Error line 2: variable @parameter-1 is undefined

If you insert spaces it works as expected:

```
.mymixin(@parameter) {
    width: ((@parameter - 1)*12px);
}
```